Special characters using jdbc.gupta.sqlbase.SqlbaseDriver
I'm developing Android application for displaying data from SQLBASE database.
We can not transfer texts with special characters: command
daten.Bezeichnung = rs.getString("bezeichnung1");
results in
daten.Bezeichnung containing text with corrupted charcters:
"Jetzt nachtr. ge�ndert BT10", while the correct text is "Jetzt nachtr. geändert BT10"
Program:
try {
                Class.forName("jdbc.gupta.sqlbase.SqlbaseDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ODBC driver load failed!");
            }

            // 1. tit_umbuchung lesen
            String sql = "SELECT titel_nr, bezeichnung1, isbn, loesch_datum "
                    + "FROM sysadm.titel "
                    + "WHERE mandant = "+config.CONFIG_MANDANT+" and ( isbn = '"+ barcode +"' or ean_nr = '"+barcode+"' or titel_nr like '"+barcode+"')";

            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(config.getConnectionURL(), config.CONFIG_USER, config.CONFIG_PASSWORD);
                 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

                if (rs.next()) {
                    TitelDaten daten = new TitelDaten();
                    daten.TitelNr = rs.getString("titel_nr");
                    daten.Bezeichnung = rs.getString("bezeichnung1");
                    daten.Isbn = rs.getString("isbn");
                    daten.Deaktiviert = rs.getDate("loesch_datum");

                    // Basislager
                    String basis_lager = "";
                    sql = "SELECT tit_lager_basis "
                            + "FROM sysadm.firm_stamm "
                            + "WHERE mandant = "+config.CONFIG_MANDANT;
                    try {
                        PreparedStatement ps0 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        ResultSet rs0 = ps0.executeQuery();

                        if (rs0.next()) {
                            basis_lager = rs0.getString("tit_lager_basis");
                        }
                        if (basis_lager.isEmpty()) {
                            basis_lager = "LA0001";
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "SQL: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

Is it possible to access data in SQLBASE containing special characters?
How access SQLBASE in android with special characters?

Please reconsider your use of JDBC on Android.

You do not specify which version of SQLBase. Assuming its something recent like v12.3, use the 'N' prefix which changes the national charset, to the SQLBase unicode charset. e.g. Define column dB column bezeichnung1 as Nvarchar(254), not varchar(254).
Also, you should read the NLS Support section in the 'DBA Guide' on how to use the country.sql file where you can set up an entire code page ( e.g. for German ) and also in the 'SQL API Reference Guide'. Also look at the 'characterset' statement for the sql.ini file in the same manual.
Specifically 'SQLPCTY'  which sets the Country file section (for example, France). This parameter tells SQLBase to use the settings in the specified section of the country.sql file. SQLBase supports English as the standard language, but it also supports many national languages including those spoken in Europe and Asia. So you must specify information that enables SQLBase to support another language in the country.sql file. If you call sqlset and specify the SQLPCTY parameter, it changes the setting of the country keyword in sql.ini. Download the appropriate manual from: SQLBase manuals
